# more infos about EncryptionMode.agile

Tags: java, encryption, apache-poi

could someone tell me more about EncryptionMode.agile?
what kind of algorithm does it use?
I have just an pw protectet xlsx file like this

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
     // EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile,  CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);

        Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
        enc.confirmPassword(password);

        System.out.println("Read in an existing OOXML file ...");
        OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(filepathname), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
```

edit:
I am generating an xlsx file, put some testdata inside and encrypt to have pw protection

edit2:
this is inside of EncriptionInfo. just look inside

```
...
/**
 * Prepares for encryption, using the given Encryption Mode, and
 *  all other parameters as default.
 * @see #EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode, CipherAlgorithm,   HashAlgorithm,   int, int, ChainingMode)
 */
public EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode encryptionMode) {
    this(encryptionMode, null, null, -1, -1, null);
}

/**
 * Constructs an EncryptionInfo from scratch
 *
 * @param encryptionMode see {@link EncryptionMode} for values, {@link EncryptionMode#cryptoAPI} is for
 *   internal use only, as it's record based
 * @param cipherAlgorithm
 * @param hashAlgorithm
 * @param keyBits
 * @param blockSize
 * @param chainingMode
 * 
 * @throws EncryptedDocumentException if the given parameters mismatch, e.g. only certain combinations
 *   of keyBits, blockSize are allowed for a given {@link CipherAlgorithm}
 */
public EncryptionInfo(
        EncryptionMode encryptionMode
      , CipherAlgorithm cipherAlgorithm
      , HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm
      , int keyBits
      , int blockSize
      , ChainingMode chainingMode
  ) {
    versionMajor = encryptionMode.versionMajor;
    versionMinor = encryptionMode.versionMinor;
    encryptionFlags = encryptionMode.encryptionFlags;

    EncryptionInfoBuilder eib;
    try {
        eib = getBuilder(encryptionMode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EncryptedDocumentException(e);
    }

    eib.initialize(this, cipherAlgorithm, hashAlgorithm, keyBits, blockSize, chainingMode);

    header = eib.getHeader();
    verifier = eib.getVerifier();
    decryptor = eib.getDecryptor();
    encryptor = eib.getEncryptor();
}...
```

this is inside AgileEncyptionInfoBuilder
      ...

```
     @Override
public void initialize(EncryptionInfo ei, CipherAlgorithm   cipherAlgorithm, HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, int keyBits, int blockSize,   ChainingMode chainingMode) {
    this.info = ei;

    if (cipherAlgorithm == null) {
        cipherAlgorithm = CipherAlgorithm.aes128;
    }
    if (cipherAlgorithm == CipherAlgorithm.rc4) {
        throw new EncryptedDocumentException("RC4 must not be used with agile encryption.");
    }
    if (hashAlgorithm == null) {
        hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.sha1;
    }
    if (chainingMode == null) {
        chainingMode = ChainingMode.cbc;
    }...
```

probably you will also need to install JCE on windows

here is an good guide:
http://suhothayan.blogspot.de/2012/05/how-to-install-java-cryptography.html
(just overwrite the .jar in lib\security ,all. on jre and jdk location)

or use  Bouncy Castle
and do not use "VelvetSweatshop" as your .xlsx password :D

Comment: Have you read the [POI encryption](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) page? ... it contains links to the official MS-OFFCRYPTO docs. Apart of that, I've provided the interface with such nice enums ... how about using them?

Comment: ... and it seems you want to [DECRYPT](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Decryption) your existing .xlsx. The code you copy&pasted is for encrypting

Comment: the documentation is not so good. 5k pages of ECMA-376...
but looking inside org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo was much better ;)

Comment: @w3Charlie If you researched it yourself, then you can post an answer yourself. It might be useful for future readers.